# Scrimba tutorial was working, suddenly stopped even trying the default

Tags: javascript, html, openai-api

I tried to follow a scrimba on creating a gpt-4 (or 3.5 for me) chatbot. This was working great, but after I downloaded it and ran it locally it just stopped working. I reset the scrimba and everything, but it just didnt work. Here is the link. I do have to right api key.
[text](https://scrimba.com/learn/buildaiapps/starter-code-coa28453fbd547f14691eb135)